# Meaning of the statement in C

Tags: c, while-loop

Can you give me some idea about the code?

C Code:

```
while((INT_STATUS() & ISR_RX_MASK)
       ||(event & TIMER_EXPIRED)
       ||(event & MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE))
{.........
```

Here:

```
event is UNT32 local variable in function   

INT_STATUS() = Some Address location

ISR_RX_MASK = 0x01 (Some value in HEX)
TIMER_EXPIRED = 0x02 (Some value in HEX)
MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE = 0x03 (Some value in HEX)
```

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that `MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE` is actually `0x04`...

Comment: Do you know about bitwise operators (like bitwise and)? Do you know about logical operator (like logical or)? If not, then I suggest you find a good book and read about those.

Comment: Look up bitwise operations in C. You should be able to understand this code after that.

Comment: [Please have a look here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0):

The loop will execute while either bit 0 of INT_STATUS() is 1, or bit 1 of event, or bit 2 of event is set to 1

Answer (score 0):

At first you will probably be interested in [binary numbers representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation).

And I suggest `MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE` is actually `0x04` and not `0x03`, more below.

In binary (`0x` means the number is represented in hexadecimal, but since all numbers below are less than 10, they could as well be shown in decimal - but we usually use hexa or octal to write number literals which interest is their binary representation), we have

```
Hexa    Binary
0x01 is 0001
0x02 is 0010
0x03 is 0011
0x04 is 0100 ...
```

And the [bitwise operator `&`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) between two numbers A and B keeps the `1` that are, in binary, in both numbers at the same place

Like (binary representation)

```
 dcba   dcba
 0110 & 0011 gives 0010 since only the 1 at position b is in both numbers
```

Finally the `while( expr )` loops while `expr` is non zero. So doing `&` between two numbers gives a result (expr) with either at least one `1` (non zero) or no `1` (zero). Thus having the `while` looping (non zero) or ending (zero).

In your case, doing

```
while((INT_STATUS() & ISR_RX_MASK)
   ||(event & TIMER_EXPIRED)
   ||(event & MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE))
```

means `while` loops if any of the three expressions is non zero (true), `||` means logical OR. Provided that `ISR_RX_MASK` is 1, `TIMER_EXPIRED` is 2 and `MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE` is (I assume) 4, you get the `while` expression

```
(INT_STATUS() & 1)
||
(event & 2)
||
(event & 4)
```

meaning the `while` goes on if the result from `INT_STATUS & 1`, ie its first bit (right side) is `1` (or *a* in my *dcba* notation shown above), or if the second bit (or *b* in my *dbca* notation) of event is `1` (from the right), or if the third bit (or *c* in my *dcba* notation) of event is `1`.

For instance if INT_STATUS is 14, ie 1110 in binary, its first bit is 0, thus the `INT_STATUS() & 1` would yield `0`.

The reason I assume MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE is 4 (or another power of 2 > 2) and not 3 is because if it is 3, or 0011 in binary, the previous `event & 2` would always be true when `event & 3` is true, and thus does not make sense in this context. And it doesn't seem MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE and TIMER_EXPIRED are related, based on their names, which is subjective, but...

Answer (score 0):

```
while((INT_STATUS() & ISR_RX_MASK) ||(event & TIMER_EXPIRED) ||(event & MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE))
```

The looping is continued if any of the following condition occurs

1) Result after performing logical AND operation between the return value of INT_STATUS() function and ISR_RX_MASK is true, Which I assume is checking for some interrupt condition

2) Result after performing logical AND operation between between variable *event*(I assume this contains value of some register) with TIMER_EXPIRED hex value is TRUE. That is, indication flag for Timer Expire will be at 1st bit poition (0000 0010)

3) Result after performing logical AND operation between between variable *event*(I assume this contains value of some register) with MEM_BLOCK_AVAILABLE hex value is TRUE. That is the indication flag for Memory Block available will be at 0th and 1st bit poition (0000 0011)